# ERROR: division leads to inf or nan at time XX, (a=x) / (b=y), where divisor b is: firstOrder.T

Tags: julia, openmodelica, fmi

I have a model designed in OpenModelica contains integrators and transfer functions and first orders. When I run this model in OMEdit, it works fine. But when I run the FMU, I have an error for division by zero for the `firstorder` block.

```
assert    | debug   | division leads to inf or nan at time 0.056, (a=7.2e+302) / (b=1e-15), where divisor b is: dd.firstOrder.T   | division leads to inf or nan at time 0.056, (a=7.2e+302) / (b=1e-15), where divisor b is: firstOrder.T
assert    | debug   | division leads to inf or nan at time 0.056, (a=7.2e+302) / (b=1e-15), where divisor b is: dd.firstOrder.T
assert    | debug   | division leads to inf or nan at time 0.056, (a=7.2e+302) / (b=1e-15), where divisor b is: dd.firstOrder.T
```

Comment: What is the value of UC?  Your PMIN and PMAX values are both set to 1, did you mean to do this or should PMIN be -1?

Comment: Does it work if you increase T4?  It looks like the when the FMU is run in julia that a value less and equal to 1e-15 is assumed to be zero.  I'm unsure where this approximation is made and how this could be controlled as I'm not familiar enough with OpenModelica or running FMU's in julia.  The model runs (with the modifications mentioned above) in Dymola.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Yes, UC=1 and ? PMIN=-1 and PMAX =1.
Yes, when I increase T4 to 0.001, it starts working. But I am not sure if this can cause problem. Because I only importing this model from a library.
I have a concern. When I run the FMU in julia, does this means that julia asks the OMC simulator to run? or Julia itself will run the FMU as a stand alone file regardless the installation of OpenModelica?